# Difference between two approaches of function pointer implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, function-pointers

I have two segments of a program in generic way

**case-1**---static global variables with reference to threads

```
static int i=10;
void fun1()
{
  cout<<"fun1 i="<<i<<endl;
  i=i+20;
}
void fun2()
{
  cout<<"fun2 i="<<i<<endl;
  i=i+30;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t t1,t2;
  void *v;
  pthread_create(&t1,NULL,(void *(*)(void *))fun1,NULL);
  pthread_create(&t2,NULL,(void *(*)(void *))fun2,NULL);
  pthread_join(t1,&v);
  pthread_join(t2,&v);
}
```

I expect here to get output of **10 and 40** but the output is **10 and 10**. Just want to know how can I get the output as desired.

**case-2**--usage of function pointers. Can't understand the usage **difference between Line-1 vs Line-2 and Line-3 vs Line-4**

```
void add()
{
  cout<<"add"<<endl;
}
void sub()
{
  cout<<"sub"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  void (*p)();
  p=add;    --Line-1
  p=&add;   --Line-2
  (*p)();   --Line-3
  p();      --Line-4
  return 0;
}
```

Here I am able to call the **assign the function pointer in two ways(Line-1 and Line-2)** and call the **function pointer in two ways(Line-3 and Line-4)**.

Just want to know what is the difference in the above example.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're asking two different questions here, so you should split them out.

Comment: Well in the first one, you're printing `i` in both functions before you change it... it's totally reasonable to be able to get 10 and 10...

Comment: About the second thing: It´s counter-intuitive, but that´s how it is. Somewhere in the standard, it´s allowed, and it´s the same.

Comment: C++ line comments use the syntax `//`. By using anything else, you force someone who would like to copy-paste your code **in order to help you** to edit before it can be compiled.

Comment: Be careful: After you join the threads in your program, `i` will end up being equal to 30, 40, 60 or something completely unexpected, because you don't protect access to `i`. You should use a mutex to access `i` in the two threads.

Comment: In any case, your program is wrong. Don't cast function pointers to a different function type, this is undefined behavior. You are just lucky that things don't explode. And then don't expect any ordering between statements that are executed in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You not likely to get 10 and 40 even if you do get the output adjusted correctly as the commentator suggests.

i is a global variable so when thread 2 starts it could find any state for i, most likely 30 so it will add another 30 to it or you could have t1  increment i to 30 then t2 increments another 30 before t1 gets to the print statement.  so t1 might print 60 and t2 might print 60 or it could be unexpected results.

this is a good example of data not being thread safe, and the amusing things that can happen.

Comment: The result 10, 40 could indeed be observed.  Even though thread 1 is launched before thread 2, without any synchronization there is no way to predict when an action in one thread will occur relative to an action in the other.  In particular, `fun2()` could run to completion before `fun1()` starts.  In that case, the output *could* be 10 and 40, but it nevertheless might be something else, including 10 and 10.  Except as established by synchronization actions, different threads don't necessarily have consistent views of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition between your threads; there's no synchronization to control who gets to `i` first. Having both threads print `10` is a reasonable outcome.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, a function designator will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to function returning `T`"; it's similar to how array expressions are converted to pointer expressions.